# Why is dispatch function relocating to home page before rendering logout function?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop a simple app for a coding challenge, since I started learning to code not that long ago. I managed to give every user a token from the backend, and send it to the backend. The problem is that when the logout button is clicked, it renders to the home page without first logging the user out.  What am I doing wrong?

Logout actions:

```
export function logOut(data) {
  localStorage.clear();
  return {
    type: "LOG_OUT",
    isLoggedIn: false,
    error: false,
    user: null
  };
}

export function logOutAction(ownProps) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(logOut());
    console.log("ownProps", ownProps);
    ownProps.history.push("/");
  };
}
```

Logout Reducer:

```
 case FETCH_LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        isError: false,
        user: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Logout button:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link
          className="logout"
          to="/"
          onClick={() => this.props.logOutAction()}
        >
          Log Out
        </Link>
        <Link to="/" className="inicio">
          <img className="homeButton" src={home} alt="home"></img>
        </Link>{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question and put your code inside actual `code`

Comment: You put your dispatched logout action on an `onClick` handler of a link that when clicked navigates to `"/"`, so of course it will navigate to `"/"` while the logout action is processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

You put your dispatched logout action on an `onClick` handler of a link that when clicked navigates to `"/"`, so of course it will navigate to `"/"` while the logout action is processing.

**Possible Solution**

One possible solution would be to add a logout page in your router and navigate there when the link is clicked. Have the logout page manage dispatching the logout action which will then dispatch *some* `FETCH_LOGOUT_SUCCESS` action to update your state. Have a separate effect waiting for mapped prop `isLoggedIn` to become false and push navigate back to home.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link className="logout" to="/logout">
        Log Out
      </Link>
      <Link to="/" className="inicio">
        <img className="homeButton" src={home} alt="home"></img>
      </Link>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

LogoutPage.jsx

```
const LogoutPage = ({ history, isLoggedIn, logOutAction }) => {
  // Empty dependency array to call effect only when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    logoutAction();
  }, []);

  // when user no longer logged in, push home route
  useEffect(() => {
    !isLoggedIn && history.push('/');
  }, [history, isLoggedIn]);

  // Display some "logout text", or spinner, whatever you 
  // want while the logout is processing
  return <Spinner />;
}
```

This also has the benefit of not not being *some* "asynchronous" navigation back to home upon your action completing, i.e.

1. the user clicks logout button, gets navigated *somewhere*
2. doesn't wait for the logout action to complete, navigates
   elsewhere
3. logout action completes and navigates them back home

By controlling it with a page the logout can still complete and they'd only navigate home if they were still on `"/logout"`.